# unable to get shipment collection by order id

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping-address, shipment

Here is my constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    //\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepo,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\CollectionFactory $shipmentCollection
){
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->orderRepo = $orderRepo;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->shipmentCollection = $shipmentCollection;
    //parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Here is the code to get order in a function:

```
$order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($id);
//$order->getShipmentsCollection(); //nothing also

$shipments = $this->shipmentCollection->create()->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order->getId())->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');
```

The result is that shipments are empty.

Anyone know how to get the shipments for an order?

Comment: are you sure that you have shipments for that specific order?

Comment: sure, now i'm forced to use direct sql to get the shipment details

Comment: please check in backend if order has any and if it has any then try to load that order in code to confirm @hkguile

Answer (score 0):

`$order` object itself has [`getShipmentsCollection()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1719) method so I think you can easily get order shipment If its has any like,

```
        $shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
```

Comment: Apparently he tried that already.

Comment: yes, tried not work

Comment: Then there might be case order does not have any shipment so please check in backend if an order has any invoice @hkguile

Comment: checked so many times the order has invoice and shipment